# Sort a list by repeated elements flutter

Tags: list, flutter, sorting, dart, duplicates

I need to sort an array by most duplicated elements like this:

```
List<String> list = ['x','y','z','x','y','y']
```

Desired output:

```
[y,y,y,x,x,z]
```

Comment: `List list = ['x','y','z','x','y','y'];
final cnt = list
.groupListsBy((i) => i)
.map((k, v) => MapEntry(k, v.length));
list.sort((a, b) => cnt[b]!.compareTo(cnt[a]!));
print(list);`

Comment: Elaborating on pskink's comment, the [`groupListsBy` extension](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableExtension/groupListsBy.html) comes from `package:collection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest moving the frequencies calculation outside of the sorting loop.

```dart
void main() {
  List<String> list = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'y'];
  Map<String, int> numberOf = {
    for (var x in list.toSet()) x: list.where((item) => item == x).length
  };
  print(list..sort((a, b) => numberOf[b]!.compareTo(numberOf[a]!)));
}
```

#### Console log

```
[y, y, y, x, x, z]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the sort function. Here is a working sample:

```
void main() {
  List list = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'y'];
  List copyList = List.from(list);
  list.sort((var a, var b) {
    int numberOfA = copyList.where((element) => element == a).length;
    int numberOfB = copyList.where((element) => element == b).length;
    return numberOfB.compareTo(numberOfA);
  });
  print(list);
}
```

Comment: You could also return `numberOfB.compareTo(numberOfA)`

Comment: @quoci Good point. Thanks for mentioning it. I'll update my answer using this syntax as it's more readable.

Comment: With this solution, you will perform the `copyList.where(...)` unnecessarily. In this case, `numberOfX * numberOfY * numberOfZ * 2`, 24 times instead of 3.

Answer (score -2):

Other example using sort function:

```
void main() {
  List list = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'y'];
  list.sort((a, b) => b.compareTo(a),);
}
```

more information about [compareTo](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/num/compareTo.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).